# log4net Udp appender in mono on Ubuntu not logging

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, mono, log4net

Running Ubuntu on a Minnow Max trying to use log4net in a mono application the Udp appender does not log to the remote location. Running the same application on a Raspberry Pi 2 with identical configs the Udp appender logs correctly. When I enable log4net logging there are no errors and the output of the log was identical on both machines. I have used nmap and Wire Shark to verify the Udp port is open and sending packets. The file appender on the Minnow is logging correctly.

C# Code

```
private static readonly ILog Logger = LogManager.GetLogger($"Drake.Mfg.DCS.{Environment.MachineName}");
public static LogLevel ConsoleLevel { get; set; }

public static void LogToNet(string message, LogLevel logLevel)
{
    try
    {
        switch (logLevel)
        {
            case LogLevel.None:
                break;
            case LogLevel.Trace:
                Logger.Trace(message);
                break;
            case LogLevel.Debug:
                Logger.Debug(message);
                break;
            case LogLevel.Info:
                Logger.Info(message);
                break;
            case LogLevel.Warn:
                Logger.Warn(message);
                break;
            case LogLevel.Error:
                Logger.Error(message);
                break;
            case LogLevel.Fatal:
                Logger.Fatal(message);
                break;
            case LogLevel.AlwaysLog:
                Logger.Info(message);
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(consoleLevel), consoleLevel, null);
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"{message}");
        Console.ResetColor();
    }
```

Log4Net.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="Main" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="dcsLog.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maximumFileSize value="1GB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="3" />
    <encoding value="utf-8" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%utcdate{ISO8601} %-8level %-28logger %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
  <appender name="UdpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.UdpAppender">
    <remoteAddress value="192.168.10.53" />
    <remotePort value="7071" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j" />
    <encoding value="utf-8" />
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="Debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="Main" />
  </root>
  <logger name="Drake.Mfg.DCS.DEI80021">
    <level value="Debug" />
    <appender-ref ref="UdpAppender" />
  </logger>
</log4net>
```

Mono

> Mono JIT compiler version 4.3.0 (master/844fc33 Tue Oct 20 14:21:50
>   EDT 2015) Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and
>   Contributors. www.mono-project.com
>           TLS:           __thread
>           SIGSEGV:       altstack
>           Notifications: epoll
>           Architecture:  amd64
>           Disabled:      none
>           Misc:          softdebug
>           LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
>           GC:            sgen

log4net

> 1.2.15

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate on the related sites http://askubuntu.com OR http://ServerFault.com (professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration). Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Thanks and Good Luck.

Comment: If you confirmed from network packets that data were sent, then it becomes a non programming question. You will have to check the network to see where the packets were lost.

Comment: Packets were sent via nmap not log4net. No packets are sent from log4net

Answer (score 1):

The Log4Net config is case sensitive as xml is. The Hostname for the Minnow was in lowercase and I was looking for upper. Because I do not have sole control over hostnames I used a To Upper.

```
ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger($"Drake.Mfg.DCS.{Environment.MachineName.ToUpper()}");
```

Fixed it now and in the future.